# How to fine tune a trained model using fast.ai with freezing feature layers?

Tags: tensorflow, model, pytorch, vision, fast-ai

I am working on a classification and detection model where I trained both models on another dataset now I am training them both again on new image data, but the model contains two models like `FPN + CNN`. I want to freeze the last layer and trained on a new dataset.

How to fine-tune this model using **fast.ai**. Please need suggestions, tutorials, etc (need some code for guidance)

Comment: Can you provide the model definition of your setup?

Comment: I am sharing the link where this model is uploaded: [model](https://github.com/Aliktk/RpSalWeaklyDet)
Here it is

Comment: Please provide the code (your code) where you are importing and initializing this model.

Comment: `# device = torch.device
model = rps.models.get_classifier(models.densenet121, 14).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model/classifier_densenet121.pth'))#, map_location=torch.device('cpu')`

#here rps is my module and load the model weights. This model contains two models e.g FPN and densenet.
From now I am confused about how to freeze the last layers and how to retrain on fewer classes?